# How create excel file with only 1 row by id from laravel export

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export

I just want to display an excel file of the line linked to the id of my patient.

But it create an excel file with all my patients & not just one.

I dont understand why, because when i make dd($patient) i only see the patient with the Id that im looking for.

Sorry for my bad english.

Enjoy :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRv4C.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEWeA.png)

Comment: Please insert your class / code here instead of an image. Makes it more useful for future references.

Comment: Did my answer help your problem?

Comment: Not really, solution was to make a function collection & not a map , & find with double array like this : $patient = [ [ ] ]; 
    return new Collection($patient);
Thanks for your help anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your collection by the id. Right now you are returning all of the elements, filter them with `Eloquent`.

```
public function collection() {
    return Patient::where('id', $this->patientId)->get();
}
```